# Does if $E(X)>E(Y)$, then $\text{Var}(X) > \text{Var}(Y)$?

Tags: expected-value, variance

Suppose two random variable $X$ and $Y$. Does if $E(X)>E(Y)$, then $\text{Var}(X) > \text{Var}(Y)$? I think not, but I am not sure how to disprove it. I know that $\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2)- E(X)^2 > \text{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2) -E(Y)^2 $ implies $E(X^2) - E(Y^2) > E(X)^2 - E(Y)^2 > 0$, but I am not sure if I can use it to disprove the hypothesis. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Absolutely not... why did you think this might be the case? The expected value is an average... and the variance is a sort of average discrepancy from the average...

Comment: It is a True of False question. I know it is false, but I can't disprove it

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=Y+1$. Then $EX>EY$ but $var (X)=var(Y)$.

Comment: Does if $E(X)>=E(Y)$, then $\text{Var}(X) >= \text{Var}(Y)$? How can you disprove that case now?

Comment: @J.Doe Think for a minute. Understand why this answer is a counterexample

Comment: Take $X$ with $EX<0$ and $var (X) \neq 0$. (For example,let $X$ take values $-1$ and $0$ with probability $\frac  1 2$ each). Take $Y=2X$. @J.Doe

Comment: @J.Doe You have to understand that expectations can be altered arbitrarily without changing the variance.